# Searching a filename

Tags: shell, shell-script, filenames

How to search a file with a given String and currentTimestamp and if not found trigger a mail?
For Ex-:I have to search a file whose filename would be like `filename_05172015`  and trigger a mail if not found in a given directory?
There will be only one file with such filename but would had extra hrs and minutes also appended to it.

Comment: do you want the extra time digits to be treated as *found* or as *not found*?

Comment: Is that one file or a list of files with the specified naming convention?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `bash` (or `zsh`) and your mail agent is sendmail then:

```
[[ -f "filename_$(date '+%m%d%Y')" ]] || echo "File is missing!" | sendmail myname@gmail.com
```

Between `[[` and `]]` we test if file exists, and if *not* then print some message and send it to *myname*.